# Select Query for the fixed length

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, text-files, fixed-width

I have an table called customer where i am selecting few columns and making its fixed length,where i need to send the values to SSIS packages for an fixed length output and is written in a text file

```
customerID:10
Mobilenumber:11
Emailaddress:256

select customerID,mobilenumber,Emailaddress from customer
```

I want to make sure my customerID is always length of 10, mobile number 11, emailaddress 256.

Answer (score 9):

You can cast them as fixed-length string datatypes, as in:

```
select cast(customerID as char(10)) as customerID,
    cast(mobilenumber as char(11)) as mobilenumber,
    cast(Emailaddress as char(256)) as Emailaddress
from customer
```

If you come across any oddity while working like this, it may be helpful to keep your [ANSI_PADDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) settings in mind.

Another way to do this might be:

```
select left(Emailaddress + replicate(' ', 256), 256)
```

Though this method is often just to apply similar logic from other languages to T-SQL.